# PHP variable type hinting better way

Tags: php, phpstorm, type-hinting

In a class I can do type hinting in a two ways.

```php
/** @var array */
private const $arr;
```

or

```php
private const array $arr;
```

Functionally there is no difference, but phpStorm keeps nagging me that I am "Missing property's type declaration". But this just looks ridiculous to me.

```php
/** @var array */
private const array $arr
```

Which is the better option (is there even a "better" option)?

Comment: I would argue to use typed properties, because then PHP can prevent silly mistakes of assigning a value of a wrong type by [throwing an error](https://3v4l.org/tp1rU). I'd focus my efforts on finding whatever plugin makes PHPStorm understand typed properties.

Comment: And as a side note: constants cannot be typed, only properties.

Comment: _Functionally there is no difference_  What?  The second way will generate a _Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError_ if you assign something other than an array, the first will not.  I assume the first way is just for phpstorm.  The second way is actually enforced by PHP.